# How can I replace multiple string at once in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The function I expected

```
some_function(original_text, "search_text", "replacement_text")
```

The value of the second & third parameters will be multiple characters. For example. The result will replace the character based on the location of the character at the second & third parameters

```
some_function("9528", "1234567890", "abcdefghij")

1 -> a
2 -> b
3 -> c
...
8 -> h
9 -> i
0 -> j
```

The result of `some_function` will be `iebh`. The nested `SUBSTITUTE` function can archive the goal but I hope to compact the complexity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way you described your requirement is best written out via [`REDUCE()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/reduce-function-42e39910-b345-45f3-84b8-0642b568b7cb), a lambda-related helper function and recently announced [to be in production](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/announcing-lambdas-to-production-and-advanced-formula/ba-p/3073293):

```
=REDUCE("9528",SEQUENCE(10),LAMBDA(x,y,SUBSTITUTE(x,MID("1234567890",y,1),MID("abcdefghij",y,1))))
```

Needless to say, this would become more vivid when used with cell-references:

[image]

Formula in `A3`:

```
=REDUCE(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(B1)),LAMBDA(x,y,SUBSTITUTE(x,MID(B1,y,1),MID(C1,y,1))))
```

---

Another, more convoluted way, could be:

```
=LET(A,9528,B,1234567890,C,"abcdefghij",D,MID(A,SEQUENCE(LEN(A)),1),CONCAT(IFERROR(MID(C,FIND(D,B),1),D)))
```

Or, as per the sceenshot above:

```
=LET(A,A1,B,B1,C,C1,D,MID(A,SEQUENCE(LEN(A)),1),CONCAT(IFERROR(MID(C,FIND(D,B),1),D)))
```

Comment: Came to propose my own solution, but found yours (with `LET`, as I don't have `LAMBDA`) better.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function Multi_Replace(Original As String, Search_Text As String, Replace_With As String) As String

'intEnd represents the last character being replaced
Dim intEnd As Long: intEnd = WorksheetFunction.Min(Len(Search_Text), Len(Replace_With))
'necessary if Search text and replace text are different lengths;

Dim intChar As Long 'to track which character we're replacing

'Replace each character individually
For intChar = 1 To intEnd
    Original = Replace(Original, Mid(Search_Text, intChar, 1), Mid(Replace_With, intChar, 1))
Next

Multi_Replace = Original

End Function
```

Comment: note that this does the characters in order, one after the other, not all at once. Therefore the output of `Multi_replace("some text here", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy", "bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")` would be `zzzz zzzz zzzz` because first it corrects a's to b's then those b's to c's, etc etc

Answer (score 0):

Maybe simpler if you do not have lambda yet: `=TEXTJOIN(,,CHAR(96+MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)))`

*Note that this will not return `0` as the expected result.

Answer (score -3):

Let's say you have a list of countries in column A and aim to replace all the abbreviations with the corresponding full names. you start with inputting the "Find" and "Replace" items in separate columns (D and E respectively), and then enter this formula in B2:

```
=XLOOKUP(A2, $D$2:$D$4, $E$2:$E$4, A2)
```

[image]

Translated from the Excel language into the human language, here's what the formula does:

Search for the A2 value (lookup_value) in D2:D4 (lookup_array) and return a match from E2:E4 (return_array). If not found, pull the original value from A2.

Double-click the fill handle to get the formula copied to the below cells, and the result won't keep you waiting:

Since the XLOOKUP function is only available in Excel 365, the above formula won't work in earlier versions. However, you can easily mimic this behavior with a combination of IFERROR or IFNA and VLOOKUP:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2, $D$2:$E$4, 2, FALSE), A2)
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, which is how to replace characters in a string

Comment: `=REPLACE(old_text, start_num, num_chars, new_text)`

old_text is the cell containing the text you want to replace.

start_num tells Excels where the text you want to replace starts within the cell.

num_chars is the number of characters you want to replace.

new_text is the text you’d like to replace that number of characters.

Comment: The result of `some_function("9528, "1234567890", "abcdefghij")` is supposed to be `iebh`, (neither `XLOOKUP` nor `REPLACE` will do that.)